# <input> button not running as button, can't find how to make run a js file

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

so in my html file i have

```
<!Doctype HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
  <title>Orange’s Game</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="game.js”></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <input type="button" onclick="startgame()" value="Start" />
  </body>
 </html>
```

and in the game.js i have

```
var startgame = function(){
 alert('GO!');
}
```

the supposed button is actually a text box, and everything I have looked up does not seem to work. I am on OS X Yosemite.

**EDIT** Ok, so I have got a button now, but now, how do I get it to run the script?

Comment: Did you close your onclick double quotes or is it just a typo?

Comment: just a typo, fixed it, but doesn't seem to look like it does

Comment: Then it's probably the quotes - they look like the word "smart" quotes instead of just the standard double quotes, so your browser is probably having trouble parsing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `“` to `"`.

It appears your text editor is changing quotation marks to smart quotes, which the browser doesn't understand.

```
<!Doctype HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
  <title>Orange’s Game</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="game.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <input type="button" onclick="startgame()" value="Start" />
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: this is what i have, after i fixed a typo. also, instead of a button, there is a text box that says "Start". also, the quotes always are slanted, i can't change them. please explain

Comment: hello, you can change your favorite text editor to https://atom.io/ or sublimetxt

Comment: Also be sure to change thous "smart" single quotes in your game.js file

Comment: I'm using TextEdit, and there are no smart quotes, that's just how they showed up when I pasted them in.

Comment: actually you're right, they do look weird. ill change them and see what happens